# d3 drag fires event even when dx and dy is 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

when i try to create a new `d3.drag()` function and bind it afterwards to my selection the "drag" event fires even when i didn't move the mouse (dx and dy = 0) on click.
I wan't to call a click handler when there was no "drag".

```
var drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragStart)
        .on('drag', dragging)
        .on('end', dragEnd);

viewPort.on('click', function () {
        clicked = true;
        })
        .call(drag);
```

I expect that clicked = true and "drag" doesn't fire when i don't move the mouse on click. Now clicked is true but "drag" is also fired.

Comment: That is how it is: a `mousedown` event will fire the dragstart event, as per [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#api-reference). To circumvent this, call the handler when dx or dy is non-zero, i.e. via a guard clause or something similar.

Comment: Tahnk you for that answer.
@Terry so you mean a guard in the "drag" event
tried that and works like a charm.
I think the "drag" event should only fire when the mouse moves...

Comment: @MrDeibl See my updated answer on the explanation why we cannot choose to not fire drag event without a mousemove event: that's because the mousedown is fired before any movement is registered, so at that point we do not know whether the mouse has moved or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elabourating on my comment a little more: a [`mousedown` event will fire the `dragstart` event in d3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#api-reference), so you can't really prevent the callback from being invoked. That, by definition, means that `dragstart` always fires before the `click` event is registered, and that's why you cannot prevent dragstart from firing in the event handler invoked bu click. The chain of event that happens when you click and release an element:

1. The `mousedown` event is fired: this triggers `dragstart` event in d3.js
2. The `mouseup` event is fired: this triggers the `dragend` event in d3.js
3. The `click` event is fired

> `click` fires after both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events have fired, in that order.
>
> [Source: see MDN docs on mouse-related events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

This also means that the `dragstart` event will always fire, even when there is no cursor/pointer/mouse movement, because at that point in time, the browser has no idea whether any movement has detected, when the `mousedown` event is triggered.

What you *can* do, however, is to set up some kind of guard clause that simply does not allow further execution of logic in the callback should the `dx` and `dy` of the event register as zero.